# Load generation using iperf

Tags: iperf

I have controller and its topology created using mininet. I need to generate traffic among hosts of topology via iperf, so that the controller is loaded and it can not handle. Is there command to generate huge number of packets at a time or large amount of traffic generation which possible by iperf?

Answer (score 0):

What does this mean "the controller is loaded and it can not handle"? Do you mean find a way to generate huge traffic to saturate the CPU? network bandwidth? Or other resource?

Just finding this tool is also useful to generate multiple threads traffic on Linux:  https://github.com/Microsoft/ntttcp-for-linux